# Good resources for those transitioning to Mac OS X from Windows

Tags: windows, switching, macos, resources

I'm going to be getting a new MacBook laptop as part of the PhD programme I've just started, but have never used Macs before in my life. I'm quite an advanced computer user (running an informal computer repair business for Windows PCs), but I can see that I might just get frustrated with it at first as I don't know some of the standard OS X ways of doing things.

Does anyone have suggestions for resources that could teach me these standard ways of doing things, or any other guides to someone transitioning from Windows?

Answer (score 8):

### [Apple - Mac Basic Tutorials](http://www.apple.com/findouthow/mac/)

Apple has made a lot of videos on how to get started and more indepth guides.

Among the tutorials there is a [PC to Mac](http://www.apple.com/findouthow/mac/#switcher) tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

Apple's guide to switching is located [here.](http://www.apple.com/lae/switch/howto/)

Comment: I just saw the edit to this and clicked the link out of curiosity. _Caveat emptor._ The site looks to be still useful, but it contains a lot of old information, like the mentioning of Palm data and the old iPod shown in one of the images.

Answer (score 6):

### [Mac OS X Hints (run by Macworld)](http://hints.macworld.com/)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO:

Here is your future:

You can read tutorials, watch videos what previous posters provide you. They are very good! but...

As advance user, prepare for hell during 1-2 weeks switching period.;)
Try to play with your new system yourself, (for sure not as root:) )

But after that I'm sure you will never return back to the windows:)

Have fun!

Comment: Hell? Sure it takes some time to get used to everything and to be as productive as you were on Windows, but I didn't find it hell at all. In fact, all the exploring showed me how cumbersome Windows sometimes can be, as opposed to OS X.

Comment: Hell at this case means "uncomfortable" :)

Answer (score 0):

Apple has retired a lot of the links posted in other answers.  Here are some that work today:

- [Mac tips for Windows switchers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204216)
- [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)